# How to deal with codependent classes in c++

Tags: c++

I have class1 that needs header of class2.And class2 that needs header of class1 to be included.

I included header of class2 in class1 and header of class1 in class2 and troubles began (in class2 I get error that says that class1 instance do not name a class)

Please can someone explain how to deal with this situation because I googled this question but didn't get what to do

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One often applicable solution to this is to simply forward-declare the classes. For example:

*class1.h*

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H

class Class2;
class Class1 {
 public:
   // ...
 private:
   // ...
   std::unique_ptr<Class2> owned_child_;
   // ...
};

#endif
```

*class2.h*

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H
#define CLASS2_H

class Class1;
class Class2 {
 public:
   // ...
 private:
   // ...
   const Class1* unowned_parent_;
   // ...
};

#endif
```

Note, however, that this strategy only works so long as you do not write code that requires the definition of the class to be available, which can be achieved when using pointers or references to the class's type. As soon as you use the class type without a reference or pointer, you will need to have available the full declaration of the class already processed and available.

Comment: Thank you
Now I know about forward declaration that solved my problem